# Are the axes of $\mathbb{C}^2$ symplectically orthogonal for a $U(2)$-invariant symplectic form?

Tags: linear-algebra, symplectic-geometry

Consider the vector space $\mathbb{C}^2$ with coordinates $(z,w)$; there is a natural $U(2)$ action on this space. Suppose we have some symplectic form $\omega$ on $\mathbb{C}^2$ which is $U(2)$ invariant.

Is it true that the axes are symplectically orthogonal with respect to $\omega$? By axes, I just mean the subspaces $\{z=0\}$ and $\{w=0\}$. By orthogonal, I mean that if $u \in \{z=0\}$ and $v \in \{w=0\}$, then $\omega(u,v) = 0$.

There are subgroups $U(1)$ which preserve the axes but there can be $U(2)$ elements that intertwine the axes and it seems that $\omega$ could be quite nonstandard; i.e. if we try to express $\omega$ with $z,w$, the formula could be quite complicated.

Comment: By a symplectic form do you mean an element in $\wedge ^2  (\mathbb C^2)^*$? If yes then a two form is a "top form", and can only be written as $\omega = f (z, w) dz\wedge d\omega$.

Comment: Yes, a symplectic form is in that exterior product and is also nondegenerate and closed.

Are you saying that the $U(2)$ invariance forces $\omega$ to take the form you wrote down? Without that assumption, we might regard $\mathbb{C}^2$ as a real 4-manifold and $\omega$ might not respect the complex structure and so $\omega$ might not take the form above.

Comment: If it is understood as a 2 form on $\mathbb R^4$, then $z=0, w=0$ are not  lines, they are two-planes. Can you write down what do you mean by orthogonal in your post.

Comment: Sure, I just made the edit. And yes, the "axes" are real two-planes but I was thinking of them as complex lines.

Comment: I was thinking of the latter; $A^* \omega = \omega$. But $A$ is linear and so its linearization is just itself anyways.

Comment: So you can check that at least at the origin, using the unitary matrix $A =\begin{pmatrix} -1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$: $\omega (u, v) = \omega (Au, Av) = \omega (-u, v)$. Not sure what to do away from the origin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are assuming that by $U(2)$-invariant, we have $A^*\omega = \omega$, where $A : \mathbb C^2 \to \mathbb C^2$ is treated as smooth mappings. Let $v\in \mathbb C^2\setminus \{0\}$. Let $u \in \mathbb C^2 \setminus \{0\}$ so that $u\cdot \bar v = 0$. Then we can show that
$$ \omega_v (v, u) = 0$$
as follows: Let $B \in U(2)$ be given by $B(av+ bu)= av-bu$. This is in $U(2)$ since $u, v$ are orthogonal. Also $B(v) = v$. Thus by assumption,

$$ \omega_v (v, u) = (B^*\omega_v) (v, u) = \omega_v (Bv, Bu) = - \omega _v (v, u) \Rightarrow \omega_v (v, u) = 0.$$

I am not sure if you can say anything more.